# Why does the output of my SQL query display incorrectly when using a custom function in the SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

So I'm learning how to define custom functions in PL/SQL.  When I use any of the functions I've defined in a regular SELECT statement the script output gets a ton of dashes added and the readability suffers.  I'm using the latest version of SQL developer.

What I want it to look like:

```
SELECT dtstage, idstage
FROM bb_basketstatus
WHERE idbasket = 4;

DTSTAGE      IDSTAGE
--------- ----------
13-FEB-12          1
13-FEB-12          5
```

What I get:

```
SELECT dtstage, status_desc_sf(idstage) Description
FROM bb_basketstatus
WHERE idbasket = 4;

DTSTAGE
---------
DESCRIPTION                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
13-FEB-12 
Order submitted                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

13-FEB-12 
Shipped
```

Is there a setting in SQL developer or something I'm missing the function definition?

Comment: Are you sure this is SQL Developer? This looks like SQL Plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a SQLPlus / SQLDeveloper script display issue.

You can manually set the width of the column with the `column ... format`  command:

```
column description format a50

select dtstage, status_desc_sf(idstage) description
from bb_basketstatus
where idbasket = 4;
```

It might also be useful to increase the default width of the lines (which defaults to 80), eg:

```
set linesize 120
```

Comment: worth noting that, in itself, increasing the linesize will be no help for viewing the sqlplus output on a fixed-width command window. At that point the command line window itself will force a line-wrap.   If I really need a longer line, I spool the output so that I can view it in a proper text editor.  Of course, the first line of attack is, as you said, to adjust the column width.